# Need to extract data from CSV file

Tags: java, regex

In my file I have below data, everything is string

Input

```
"abcd","12345","success,1234,out",,"hai"
```

The output should be like below

Column 1:   "abcd"

Column 2:   "12345"

Column 3:   "success,1234,out"

Column 4:   null

Column 5:   "hai"

We need to use comma as a delimiter , the null value is comming without double quotes.

Could you please help me to find a regular expression to parse this data

Comment: Did you miss comma in your output ?

Comment: what you have tried ? please put your code here.

Comment: No Regex needed. Just split that string on `","`, remove all `"` ( first and last entry ) -> you'll have a `String[]` like `[[abcd] [12345] [success,1234,out][null] [hai]]` (where [null] is a `NULL` - not the String "null") . This you can then join again into your desired format.

Comment: [Tutorial by Mykong](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/) - maybe this can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a tool like `CSVReader` from OpenCsv https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/

You can even configure a `CSVParser` (used by the reader) to output `null` on several conditions. From the doc :

> ```
> /**
>  * Denotes what field contents will cause the parser to return null:  EMPTY_SEPARATORS, EMPTY_QUOTES, BOTH, NEITHER (default)
>  */
> public static final CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator DEFAULT_NULL_FIELD_INDICATOR = NEITHER;
> ```

Comment: Sorry I am using Talend etl tool for loading this CSV file

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regular Expression

```
"([^"]*)"
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/WpgU9W/1

```
Match 1
Group 1.    1-5     `abcd`

Match 2
Group 1.    8-13    `12345`

Match 3
Group 1.    16-32   `success,1234,out`

Match 4
Group 1.    36-39   `hai`
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply....I need to capture NULL also ie ,,

The column 4 should be NULL, since in source we are getting ,,

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`("[^"]+")|(?<=,)(,)`](https://regex101.com/r/uzJWJY/1) regex you may find either quoted strings (`"[^"]+"`), which should be treated as is, or commas preceded by commas, which denote null field values. All you need now is iterate through the matches and check which of the two capture groups defined and output accordingly:

```
String input = "\"abcd\",\"12345\",\"success,1234,out\",,\"hai\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]+\")|(?<=,)(,)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
int col = 1;
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println("Column " + col + ": " + matcher.group(1));
        col++;
    } else if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        System.out.println("Column " + col + ": null");
        col++;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/QmCzPE

Answer (score 0):

Step #1:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(,,)";
final String string = "\"abcd\",\"12345\",\"success,1234,out\",,\"hai\"\n"
     + "\"abcd\",\"12345\",\"success,1234,out\",\"null\",\"hai\"";
final String subst = ",\"null\",";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

**Original Text:**

```
"abcd","12345","success,1234,out",,"hai"
```

**Transformation: (with null)**

```
"abcd","12345","success,1234,out","null","hai"
```

**Step #2: (use REGEXP)**

```
"([^"]*)"
```

**Result:**

```
abcd
12345
success,1234,out
null
hai
```

Credits:

Emmanuel Guiton [https://stackoverflow.com/users/7226842/emmanuel-guiton] REGEXP

Comment: Thanks for your answere. I am using Talend and trying to read a CSV file.
So is there any way to get a complete regular expression to get all the data including the NULL ie ,,.
I can use this regular expression as a column delimiter while reading the text file

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Replace function:

```
final String inuput = "\"abcd\",\"12345\",\"success,1234,out\",,\"hai\"";
System.out.println(inuput);

String[] strings = inuput
        .replaceAll(",,", ",\"\",")
        .replaceAll(",,", ",\"\",") // if you have more then one null successively
        .replaceAll("\",\"", "\";\"")
        .replaceAll("\"\"", "")
        .split(";");

for (String string : strings) {

    String output = string;
    if (output.isEmpty()) {
       output = null;
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
```